# HTML link for add contact to whatsapp

Tags: android, html

I need to put a deep link in my HTML for adding a contact to the Phone and then begin a new conversation in whatsapp.

I found this code

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!">Send text to whatsapp</a>
```

And this one:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?abid=username&text=Hello%2C%20World!">Send text to user</a>
```

I need to open a conversation with a specific contact even if I don't have the contact. My first question is, where can I get the username for whatsapp?

Having the abid I can try if it works but I dont know where to get that data.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=NUMBER">Send Message</a>
```

Without "+" or "00" at the beginning, just start country code and the number.
Example USA is +12025599025 then in the code given, replace NUMBER with 12025599025

Answer (score 6):

this was worked for me:

`whatsapp://send?text=MESSAGE&phone=+NUMERO&abid=+NUMERO`

Obviusly "+NUMERO" is the wsp number and "MESSAGE" the preloaded message put in `in`href` attribute

Comment: In my case it seems that the number is not added, instead it attemps to send a message to a given number but does not add the contact to your phone (most likely for security reasons since whatsapp leverages the contacts repository of the smartphone).

Answer (score 2):

### Recent solution (July 2017)

Malki's answer does solves the issue, but recently there's been published an official Whatsapp API I mentioned in [THIS OTHER ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45227158/1920145) (because S.O. policies I had to put a link to the solution, no duplicates).

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't directly add the contact but allows you to open a copnversation with a concrete number, it can be very usefull to use it in your web sites. I've just found that it is possible to open a conversation to a number [Using Click to Chat](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/general/26000030)

> To create your own link with a pre-filled message that will
>   automatically appear in the text field of a chat, use
>   `https://wa.me/whatsappphonenumber/?text=urlencodedtext` where
>   whatsappphonenumber is a full phone number in international format and
>   URL-encodedtext is the URL-encoded pre-filled message.

Example:`https://wa.me/15551234567?text=I'm%20interested%20in%20your%20car%20for%20sale`

**NOTE:** It opens WhastApp application if you click the link using a mobile phone browser (at least from Android)

Answer (score 1):

The ABID (address book ID) is for an ID, not a name on your contact list.

In [Whatsapp URL Scheme Documentation](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013) There are not (yet) documentation to send message to a specific contact.

The best way i found is to add the contact using this html code:

```
<a href="tel:0123456789">add number</a>
```

(this will open Contacts app from your phone)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can create a link to send a WhatsApp message to a particular number.

Notice that you don't need to add the '+' symbol before the country -code. Just start with the country-code followed by the WhatsApp number:

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=919854098540" target="_blank">Link Icon</a>
```